# c#: copy variable to byte array

Tags: c#, built-in-types

How do I copy a double, int, bool or other built-in type to a byte array in C#?

I need to do it to use the `FileStream.Write()` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`BitConverter.GetBytes()` can convert primitive types to byte arrays.

Comment: Yes and for strings you would need to use GetBytes on your encoding object.

Comment: Why people keeps voting this answer? The question is about copying primitive types to a byte array, not converting them.

Comment: @Trap, How would you copy a non-byte type's value to a byte array without converting?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of converting each value to a byte array, you can use a `BinaryWriter` to write the values to the file stream.

Example:

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream)) {
   writer.Write(1);
   writer.Write(1.0);
   writer.Write(true);
   writer.Write("Hello");
}
```